# using a variable when calling a macro

Tags: variables, macros, while-loop, sas

I'm an amateur sas user, so forgive my lacking vocabulary!

```
%macro wtv(n);
var&n = 1;
%mend; 

do while (n < 10);
n+1;
%wtv(n); /*here's the problem I think*/
end;
```

Here's the idea: I'd like to use `n` in my macro input (where the comment is). The code is just a simplified example obviously, this is not exactly what I'd like to do, but you get the idea! How could I use a variable (`n` for instance) when calling a macro? The code I just wrote would use n as a character, and return `varn = 1`, instead of `var1 = 1`, `var2 = 1`, `var3 = 1` ... `var9 = 1`.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

As an amateur, the first thing you'll need to understand are several rules of macros:

1. Macros output text/code.
2. Macros operate BEFORE code is run/compiled/submitted.
3. Always try to understand what is in "macro land" and what is in "data step land".  Because everything in "macro land" will be calculated first, then the result of that will be output and run as the "data step land code".  If you try to refer to a variable from "data step land" in a macro, you're going to run into problems because the macro doesn't know about/can't see "data step land".

So what's going wrong in your example?

Your "do while" loop is in data step land. "%wtv(n)" is in macro land and runs before the data step code.

The macro sees the input text "n" as its parameter, and dutifully writes out:

```
varn = 1;
```

n has been substituted for &n because the text "n" was fed in as the value of the macro variable "&n".  Macro land finished its operation, and the code that remains looks like:

```
do while (n < 10);
n+1;
varn = 1;
end;
```

This code executes dutifully, but "varn = 1;" will just stay the same through each iteration of the while loop, which is presumably not what you wanted to happen.

So what do you want to happen?  If you want to use code to loop over variables indexed by n, use an array like Hong Ooi's response suggested.  Generally, my advice is not to use macros when regular code will suffice.

But there's the off chance you actually want to use macro looping magic for some productive reason instead.  It happens.  If that's the case, maybe you don't want a data step "do while" loop, but a macro one instead.  In such a case, your wtv macro could then become:

```
%macro wtv(n);
%local i;  /* explicit declarations are a good habit to get into */
%let i = 1;
%do %while (&i <= &n); 
var&i = 1;
%let i = %eval(&i + 1);
%end;
%mend wtv;  /* explicitly named mend statements are also good */
```

Now, you can call %wtv(5), and it should resolves to the data step code:

```
var1 = 1;
var2 = 1;
var3 = 1;
var4 = 1;
var5 = 1;
```

You just need to feed it a respectable number and include it in a data step, but the downside is you need to do this without referencing data step variables.  Because macros run before the data step, they can't use information derived from the data step at run time to drive their own operation.

If you already know this number when you're writing your code, you're set.  In such a case, you don't need a data step "do while" loop or arrays at all.

Comment: +1 -- This is a tough concept, especially if one is used to the way most modern programming languages work.  Great job explaining the nuances of it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a macro for this. Use an array instead.

```
data;
    array var{9} var1-var9;
    do i=1 to 9;
       var{i} = 1;
    end;
    ...
```

In fact, you don't even need a loop; you can initialise your variables directly in the `array` statement.

```
    array var{9} var1-var9 (9*1);
```